# error while compiling MFC Application with winemaker

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, wine, winexe

I have a solution and 3 VC++ project (1 shared project)

1. DLL library project  + common dll project  [DLL +DLL]
2. MFC Application project + common dll project [EXE + DLL]

Both projects runs on windows platform(ported from VS6 to VS2010). It is using Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0.

Now I am trying to run them on linux using wine.

I have SUCCEED in compiled `commondll.a` in linux using winemaker as it did not had more dependency.

Now when i compile dll library or MFC exe project it throws some what similar error for both

#### Problem

```
    In file included from /usr/include/msxml.h:284:0,
    from /usr/include/urlmon.h:355,
    from /usr/include/objbase.h:489,
    from /usr/include/ole2.h:25,
    from /usr/include/atlcore.h:25,
    from /usr/include/afxstr.h:31,
    from /usr/include/afx.h:755,
    from /usr/include/afxwin.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/oaidl.h:445:1: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/oaidl.h:460:1: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    In file included from /usr/include/atlconv.h:27:0,
    from /usr/include/atltrace.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlexcept.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlchecked.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlcore.h:31,
    from /usr/include/afxstr.h:31,
    from /usr/include/afx.h:755,
    from /usr/include/afxwin.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/atlalloc.h:80:30: error: invalid suffix "i64" on integer constant
    /usr/include/atlalloc.h:81:30: error: invalid suffix "i64" on integer constant
    /usr/include/atlalloc.h:89:39: error: invalid suffix "ui64" on integer constant
    In file included from /usr/include/atlconv.h:27:0,
    from /usr/include/atltrace.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlexcept.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlchecked.h:17,
    from /usr/include/atlcore.h:31,
    from /usr/include/afxstr.h:31,
    from /usr/include/afx.h:755,
    from /usr/include/afxwin.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/atlalloc.h:629:3: error: #error Only supported for X86, AMD64 and IA64
    In file included from /usr/include/afxwin.h:65:0,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:227:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:227:1: error: pasting "_InitCommonControls" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:227:1: error: pasting "m__InitCommonControls" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:228:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:228:1: error: pasting "_InitCommonControlsEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:228:1: error: pasting "m__InitCommonControlsEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:229:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:229:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:229:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    In file included from /usr/include/afxwin.h:65:0,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:230:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:230:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:230:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:231:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:231:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:231:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_GetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:232:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:232:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:232:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_SetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:233:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:233:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Add" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:233:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Add" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:234:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:234:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_ReplaceIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:234:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_ReplaceIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:235:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:235:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:235:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_SetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:236:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:236:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:236:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_GetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:237:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:237:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetOverlayImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:237:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_SetOverlayImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:238:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:238:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Draw" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:238:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Draw" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:239:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:239:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Replace" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:239:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Replace" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:240:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:240:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_AddMasked" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:240:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_AddMasked" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:241:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:241:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DrawEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:241:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DrawEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:242:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:242:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DrawIndirect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:242:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DrawIndirect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:243:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:243:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Remove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:243:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Remove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:244:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:244:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:244:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_GetIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:245:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:245:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_LoadImageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:245:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_LoadImageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:246:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:246:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_LoadImageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:246:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_LoadImageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:247:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:247:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Copy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:247:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_Copy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:248:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:248:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_BeginDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:248:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_BeginDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:249:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:249:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_EndDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:249:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_EndDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:250:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:250:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragEnter" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:250:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DragEnter" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:251:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:251:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragLeave" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:251:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DragLeave" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:252:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:252:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragMove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:252:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DragMove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:253:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:253:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetDragCursorImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:253:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_SetDragCursorImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:254:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:254:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragShowNolock" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:254:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_DragShowNolock" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:255:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:255:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetDragImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:255:1: error: pasting "m__ImageList_GetDragImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:256:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:296:1: error: pasting "_DPA_Sort" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:296:1: error: pasting "m__DPA_Sort" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:297:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:297:1: error: pasting "_DPA_Search" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:297:1: error: pasting "m__DPA_Search" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:298:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:298:1: error: pasting "_Str_SetPtrW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:298:1: error: pasting "m__Str_SetPtrW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:300:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:320:1: error: pasting "_RemoveWindowSubclass" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:320:1: error: pasting "m__RemoveWindowSubclass" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:477:1: error: pasting "AfxCtxLoadLibraryExW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:477:1: error: pasting "LoadLibraryExW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:496:1: error: pasting ")" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:496:1: error: pasting "_InitNetworkAddressControl" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.h:496:1: error: pasting "m__InitNetworkAddressControl" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    In file included from /usr/include/afxwin.h:5439:0,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:37:1: error: pasting "AfxInitCommonControls" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:37:1: error: pasting "_InitCommonControls" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:38:1: error: pasting "AfxInitCommonControlsEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:38:1: error: pasting "_InitCommonControlsEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:39:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:39:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:40:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:40:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:41:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_GetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:41:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:42:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_SetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:42:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetImageCount" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:43:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Add" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:43:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Add" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:44:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_ReplaceIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:44:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_ReplaceIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:45:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_SetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:45:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:46:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_GetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:46:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetBkColor" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:47:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_SetOverlayImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:47:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetOverlayImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:48:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Draw" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:48:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Draw" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:49:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Replace" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:49:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Replace" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:50:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_AddMasked" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:50:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_AddMasked" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:51:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DrawEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:51:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DrawEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    In file included from /usr/include/afxwin.h:5439:0,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:52:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DrawIndirect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:52:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DrawIndirect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:53:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Remove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:53:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Remove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:54:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_GetIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:54:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetIcon" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:55:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_LoadImageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:55:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_LoadImageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:56:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_LoadImageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:56:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_LoadImageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:57:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Copy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:57:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Copy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:58:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_BeginDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:58:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_BeginDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:59:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_EndDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:59:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_EndDrag" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:60:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DragEnter" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:60:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragEnter" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:61:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DragLeave" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:61:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragLeave" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:62:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DragMove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:62:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragMove" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:63:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_SetDragCursorImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:63:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_SetDragCursorImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:64:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_DragShowNolock" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:64:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_DragShowNolock" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:65:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_GetDragImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:65:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_GetDragImage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:66:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Read" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:66:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Read" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:67:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_Write" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:67:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_Write" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:70:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_ReadEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:70:1: error: pasting "_ImageList_ReadEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:71:1: error: pasting "AfxImageList_WriteEx" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    In file included from /usr/include/afxwin.h:5439:0,
    from /usr/include/afxext.h:17,
    from /usr/include/afxole.h:19,
    from /usr/include/afxctl.h:21,
    from stdafx.h:11,
    from epsapi.cpp:1:
/usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:80:1: error: pasting "AfxCreateMappedBitmap" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:80:1: error: pasting "_CreateMappedBitmap" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:81:1: error: pasting "AfxDrawStatusTextA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:81:1: error: pasting "_DrawStatusTextA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:82:1: error: pasting "AfxDrawStatusTextW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:82:1: error: pasting "_DrawStatusTextW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:83:1: error: pasting "AfxCreateStatusWindowA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:83:1: error: pasting "_CreateStatusWindowA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:84:1: error: pasting "AfxCreateStatusWindowW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:84:1: error: pasting "_CreateStatusWindowW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:85:1: error: pasting "AfxMenuHelp" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:85:1: error: pasting "_MenuHelp" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:86:1: error: pasting "AfxShowHideMenuCtl" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:86:1: error: pasting "_ShowHideMenuCtl" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:87:1: error: pasting "AfxGetEffectiveClientRect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:87:1: error: pasting "_GetEffectiveClientRect" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:88:1: error: pasting "AfxMakeDragList" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:88:1: error: pasting "_MakeDragList" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:89:1: error: pasting "AfxDrawInsert" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:97:1: error: pasting "_DSA_GetItemPtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:98:1: error: pasting "AfxDSA_InsertItem" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:98:1: error: pasting "_DSA_InsertItem" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:99:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:99:1: error: pasting "_DPA_Create" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:100:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:100:1: error: pasting "_DPA_Destroy" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:101:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_DeletePtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:106:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_InsertPtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:106:1: error: pasting "_DPA_InsertPtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:107:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_GetPtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:107:1: error: pasting "_DPA_GetPtr" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:108:1: error: pasting "AfxDPA_Sort" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:108:1: error: pasting "_DPA_Sort" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:142:1: error: pasting "AfxDefSubclassProc" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:142:1: error: pasting "_DefSubclassProc" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:143:1: error: pasting "AfxDrawShadowText" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:143:1: error: pasting "_DrawShadowText" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:145:1: error: pasting "AfxCreatePropertySheetPageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:145:1: error: pasting "_CreatePropertySheetPageA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:146:1: error: pasting "AfxCreatePropertySheetPageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:146:1: error: pasting "_CreatePropertySheetPageW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:147:1: error: pasting "AfxDestroyPropertySheetPage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:147:1: error: pasting "_DestroyPropertySheetPage" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:148:1: error: pasting "AfxPropertySheetA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:148:1: error: pasting "_PropertySheetA" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:149:1: error: pasting "AfxPropertySheetW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
    /usr/include/afxcomctl32.inl:149:1: error: pasting "_PropertySheetW" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Comment: What Windows SDK version are you using?

Comment: it is Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0

Comment: i made a default win32 application in windows(checked ATL option) while creating project. I copied this project on ubuntu for winelib it still gives (http://pastebin.com/FWUJa1ie) atl error in header files. i think i have not configured atl headers properly, are there ATL header while compiling through wine. My current wine version is 1.6